# Form submitting to a different url as opposed to within the same page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that submits within the same url (eg. form.co.uk is where the form is and upon successfully submitting rather than going to a confirmation page with a different URL it stays on form.co.uk and gives the 'thanks for contacting us' confirmation on the same page.

However I need to change this so upon submitting it goes to a different url (just a thank you page)

How would I go about this?

html

```
<div class="width-inner">
    <?if ($c->submitted && count($c->errors) == 0): ?>

    <div class="thankyou-box">
        <h2>Thank you for your enquiry</h2>
        <h3>We'll get back to you as soon as we can.</h3>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', "/thanks"]);
    </script>

    <? else: ?>

    <div class="contact-box left" style="width:650px;">
        <form action="form.php" method="post">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <h3>Get in touch now.</h3>
            </div>
            <? if(count($c->errors) > 0): ?>
            <div class="error">
                There was a problem with your enquiry
            </div>
            <? endif; ?>
            <div class="vspace20"></div>

            <label>Your Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="<?= $c- >requestEmpty('name') ? 'invalid' : '' ?>" value="<?= @$_REQUEST['name'] ?>"/>
            <div class="required">Required field</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email"  class="<?= $c- >requestEmpty('email') ? 'invalid' : '' ?>" value="<?= @$_REQUEST['email'] ?>"/>
            <div class="required">Required field</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <hr/>

            <label>Enquiry:</label>
            <textarea name="enquiry"  class="<?= $c->requestEmpty('enquiry') ? 'invalid' : '' ?>">I  would like to contact you.</textarea>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <hr/>
            <input type="hidden" name="extra" value="<?=  @$_REQUEST['extra'] ?>"/>
            <div class="notice">Your details will not be used for marketing purposes</div> <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-submit right" value="Claim  Now" name="submit"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

code for the handler

```
<?php



class Contact {

var $submitted = false;
var $errors = array();
var $template = "Name: %s\r\nEmail Address: %s\r\nEnquiry: %s";

public function __construct() {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $this->submitted = true;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    $requiredFields = array(
        'name', 'email'
    );
    foreach($requiredFields as $key) {
        if ($this->requestEmpty($key)) {
            $this->errors[] = $key;
        }
    }
    if (count($this->errors) == 0) {
        $this->_sendForm();
    }

}

private function _sendForm() {
    $body = sprintf($this->template,
            $_REQUEST['name'],
            $_REQUEST['email'],
            $_REQUEST['enquiry'] . "\r\n" . $_REQUEST['extra']);

    $headers = 'From: auto@magnetikmedia.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: auto@magnetikmedia.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail("johnfarrell2012@gmail.com", "New contact form", $body, $headers, "-     fauto@magnetikmedia.co.uk");

header("Location: thank_you.php"); 
exit;
}

public function requestEmpty($key) {
    if (empty($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
        return true;
    }
    if (trim($_REQUEST[$key]) == "") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}

?>
```

I guess it must be something to do with the top if else statement ie. I want to say 'if successful and no errors then go to www.whatever.com' but how would I write this?

Comment: Usually it's done in a PHP mail handler, where upon successful submission, would redirect via a header function. I.e.: `if(mail($to....); header("Location: thank_you.php"); exit;} else{ echo "Mail not sent"; exit;}`

Comment: Post your PHP handler, need to see what's inside THAT and not your form so I can show you exactly how. But you can base yourself on my example above.

Comment: Code for handler updated on the original question, Thanks for the help guys, as always a great site for help :) I will try the options out.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your form PHP page, add this, altered for your URL:

```
$success = "success.html";
header("Location: " . $success);
```

Comment: Move the handling of the FORM out of that file and put it in a separate file or put this tidbit in your 'if form submitted'

Comment: Why have extra code? You could crunch that down to 34 chars with `header("Location: success.html");` - you have 60.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then why use double quotes. PHP will have to interpret that data, looking for variables, and such. HA!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to change your HTML,

```
<form action='page.php' method='post'>
```

or send a header after your PHP is handled on that same page, like

```
header('LOCATION:page.php'); die();
```

. Make sure you use `die();` to kill the current page.

Comment: FAIL => `header('LOCATION:page.php'); die();`

Comment: `page.php` is a different page in the second example. Notice the word `or` and not `and`.

Comment: It's because there is no space between your colon and `page.php`, that's why it will fail.

Comment: That works all the time for me, without the space between the colon.

Comment: Well that is really strange. So many times I've reworked forms for people where they said the header wasn't working as expected, then upon using a space after the colon, it worked. Now I am completely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your edit, try this then:

**Quick opening note:** You could also set `header` to an external URL such as:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

and the `http://` must be included.

---

### Redirection after mail examples:

```
mail("johnfarrell2012@gmail.com", "New contact form", $body, $headers, "- fauto@magnetikmedia.co.uk");

header("Location: thank_you.php"); 
exit;
}
```

### And to check if mail was sent successfully:

(We simply add an `if/else` condition.)

```
if(mail("johnfarrell2012@gmail.com", "New contact form", $body, $headers, "- fauto@magnetikmedia.co.uk"));

header("Location: thank_you.php"); 
exit;
}

else {
echo "Mail not sent";
exit;
}
```

More on the header function can be viewed on the PHP.net Website.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php**

Comment: I tried this Fred and I am getting an error. I added the extra bit of code to the handler and I have updated my question with the current code but upon submitting, i get the error 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data02/c3806400/public_html/includes/doctype.php:130) in /data02/c3806400/public_html/controllers/Contact-direct.php on line 50